# How to install flatpickr via npm and with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, flatpickr

I've created basic HTML file, initiated npm with `npm init`, installed flatpickr module with `npm i flatpickr --save` and webpack with `npm i webpack webpack-cli --save-dev`.

My HTML file looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="flatpickr" name="flatpickr" id="flatpickr">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JavaScript file like this:

```js
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';

flatpickr('.flatpickr', {
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "F, d Y H:i"
});
```

My `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

After I do `npx webpack`, and open my `index.html`, I see the input field, but when I click on it, nothing happens. But, I've got some flatpickr fields that are created below.

This screenshot is from the live preview of `index.html`, and these fields are below the input field which should invoke flatpickr's datepicker.

[flatpickr's fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvJGh.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: @LinDu Yes, I do. I updated my original post with the config.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the same problem as you.  I'm using flatpickr with just simple webpack and typescript setup.

I had to explicitly reference the css from my html to get it to work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).